# Put a document into a php variable with two types of quotes

Tags: php

Hi I have documents what i need to store within a php variable in the same file.
The problem is that the code has single and double quotes, so I can not store it within a variable.

```
//one of many problem examples
$html ="<span onclick="document.getElementById('video-modal').style.display = 'none';">X</span>";
```

So the question is how can I put this to a variable and keep it in the same file?
I tried this qote `, otherwise I am not sure maybe with ob_start or is there an easier way? Backslashes to escape is also not a solution, because in this way I would have to do a lot of manual work to do this. I also want to avoid doing it into a separate file.

Comment: Backslashes are used to escape characters.

Comment: @user3783243 this is no answer, since I have to many html elements to change for this solution....

Comment: You might want to look into [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Since heredoc doesn't use quotes, you won't need to modify/escape the contents.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson a really good idea. I tried it but somehow it did not work. 
Here is my example 
$html = <<<EOT <span onclick="document.getElementById('video-modal').style.display = 'none';">X</span>    EOT;

Any idea?

Comment: I can't really see if it's correct without seeing the line breaks as well. The important part is to write the contents on a new line after `<<<EOT` (not dire) and then have the closing `EOT;` on a new line without any tabs or spaces before it or after the semi colon. It should be the only thing on that line.

Comment: or why not use addEventListener that way you only need a html element with a class or id..